# PHP forks & Shell_exec

Tags: php, fork, shell-exec

i have a php script with the following code:

```
<?php

$task_pids = array();

for ( $i = 0; $i <= 60; $i++ )
{
    $task_pids[$i] = pcntl_fork();
    if ( ! $task_pids[$i] )
    {
        $count = intval( trim( shell_exec( "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i \"http://127.0.0.1:23931\" 2>&1 | grep -v grep | grep -c 'Stream #0'" ) ) );

        posix_kill( getmypid(), 9 );
    }
}


for ( $i = 0; $i <= 60; $i++ )
{
    pcntl_waitpid( $task_pids[$i], $status, WUNTRACED );
}

?>
```

The above script opens 60 PHP Processes and run the above command inside shell_exec.
This is just an example script of what i am doing.

The above script sometimes it stucks and never ends, and sometimes it completes successfully. [But most of the time it stucks]

Do you have an idea why this might be happening? Is there any solution for that?
If i use timeout in the command with /usr/bin/timeout it ends successfully but i want to take the ffmpeg output.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

replace the pcntl_wait cycle by:

```
while(pcntl_waitpid( 0, $status)!=-1);
```